# Can you create custom filter modules or functions for nxlog?

Tags: nxlog

We are using nxlog community edition. Is there any way in the conf file to call out to a custom module that filters and modifies messages? I would like to build this in a more sensible language than the one nxlog uses.

We also need a little persistence so I'm thinking redis.

I can't find anything in the extensive documentation that tells me how to do this. It's basically an extension to the language that I need.A custom module.

Answer (score 0):

It supports [python](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/xm_python.html), [perl](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/xm_perl.html) and [ruby](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/xm_ruby.html) if these qualify as more sensible languages.

For redis persistence see [om_redis](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/om_redis.html).
AFAIK some of these are NXLog EE only.